# An ID must not contain whitespace validation issue using http://validator.w3.org/

Tags: html

I've been searching on here and Google trying to find a way to fix the below validation error message, but nothing is quite like my example. I'happy for any direction to a question that already exists to help resolve this.

> Line 71, Column 47: Bad value content skel-cell-important for
>   attribute id on element div: An ID must not contain whitespace.

Does this mean I have to change (I've tried with out success)

> `<div id="content skel-cell-important">`

to something like the below to get around this? or is there another way to pass the http://validator.w3.org/ validation?

> `<div id="content-skel-cell-important">`

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use the `id` attribute as others would normally use the `class` attribute. Any reason that you can't use `class` instead of `id`?

Comment: Seems sbeliv01 has your answer, but in future you'll want to outline what exactly it is you're trying to accomplish, so you can get more definite answers rather than guesses in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use the id attribute as others would normally use the class attribute.

Try using `<div class="content skel-cell-important">` instead.